# before_validation fails in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Rails 3.2.11, Mac OS X Mountain Lion, Ruby 1.9.3

So I have this piece of code:

```
class Points < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :id, :presence => true

before_create :validate_points

def validate_points
  if self.amount < 0
    Rails.logger.error "Invalid amount of points"
  else
    save!
  end
end
```

end

I want to restrict users from inserting negative values. But for some reason the validate_points method doesn't work. Anything I'm doing wrong? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `validates_numericality_of` method provided by Rails

```
validates :amount, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
```

UPDATE: issues on your code

There are a couple of issues on your code.

1. You are using `before_create` which is called right before the record is saved to the database.  The only way to prevent a db commit in this way is to return false in the callback but this is not good practice.
2. `validate_points` calls `save!` but is called in a `before_create` callback so you're saving your record 2x **UPDATE: as pointed out by rxing, this will cause an infinite loop instead of just 2 saves to the database**

if you don't want to use the built in validation, try the following

```
validate :validates_amount_points

def validates_amount_points
  errors.add_to :amount, 'must be greater than or equal to 0' if amount < 0
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use 'validation' instead of the before_create hook.
BTW, your before_create is not correct either. It would raise SystemStackError: stack level too deep since "save!" will tigger before_create recursively.

Comment: that is incorrect. `before_create` will only be triggered once. If it was `before_save`, then I'd agree with you.

Comment: when you save for one new_record, before_create will be called recursively since it has no chance to become one 'existing record'.
That's why it will be in dead loop for before_create.

Comment: hmm interesting. now that I think more about it, you're right. it will never go past the point of creating the record. nice catch!